# I/O error on POST request while sending query parameters

Tags: java, post, http-post, resttemplate, query-string

I am using the below code for hitting a POST request with two query parameters.
My POSTMAN URL looks like this : https://example.com/xyz?username=john.doe&target_site=mysite .Hitting this URL using POST method on POSTMAN works fine. Not sure why I am getting error while doing it from Java.

```
            UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://example.com/xyz");
            Map<String, String> criteria = new HashMap<>();
            criteria.put("username",  "john.doe");
            uriBuilder.queryParam("username", "{username}");
            criteria.put("target_site", "mysite");
            uriBuilder.queryParam("target_site", "{target_site}");
            ParameterizedTypeReference<Object> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Object>() {
            };
            ResponseEntity<Object> response =
            restTemplate.exchange(
            uriBuilder.build().toUriString(),
            HttpMethod.POST,
            null,
            responseType,
            criteria);
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

Getting the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://example.com/xyz": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:617)
    at com.mfsi.appbuilder.AppBuilderApplication.main(AppBuilderApplication.java:49)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:734)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: You can refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore for more details on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configuring JSSE System Properties, specifically point to client certificate store.

Via command line:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststores/client.ts com.progress.Client
```

or via Java code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
...
Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
systemProps.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","passwordForKeystore");
systemProps.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","pathToKeystore.ks");
systemProps.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "pathToTruststore.ts");
systemProps.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","passwordForTrustStore");
System.setProperties(systemProps);
...
```

For more refer to details on [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_MQ_Enterprise/7.1/html/Security_Guide/files/SSL-SysProps.html) site.

Comment: I am not sure about the code. Am I sending the parameters correctly?

Comment: You are, but this says that you do not have valid certification so you must correct this. ("unable to find valid certification path to requested target")